# Reactjs checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why I can checked and unchecked the checkbox? I dont know why the `School Organization` works fine, I can unchecked and checked but in `Student` I cant, why? please help thanks

```
export const STUDENT_ROLES_PERMISSIONS = [
  {
    actions: ['*'],
    code: 'admin',
    name: 'Admin',
  },
  {
    actions: ['create', 'update', 'read'],
    code: 'contributor',
    name: 'Contributor',
  },
  {
    actions: ['read'],
    code: 'viewer',
    name: 'Viewer',
  },
];

export const SCHOOL_GROUPING = [
  {
    name: 'School Organization',
    type: ['person', 'role'],
    withIcon: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Student',
    withIcon: false,
  },
];
```

//

```
 const isCheked = (role, type) => {
    const selectedSchemas = type.filter((schema) => {
      if (role.code === 'admin') {
        return selectedPermissions.find((perm) => {
          return schema === perm.type && perm.action === '*';
        });
      }

      const access = selectedPermissions
        .filter((perm) => {
          return (
            schema === perm.type &&
            role.actions.includes(String(perm.action).toLowerCase())
          );
        })
        .map((perm) => {
          return String(perm.action).toLowerCase();
        });

      const isEqual = _.isEqual(role.actions.sort(), access.sort());
      if (isEqual && role.code === 'viewer') {
        const hasStrayPermission = selectedPermissions.find((perm) => {
          return (
            schema === perm.type &&
            ['create', 'update', '*'].includes(
              String(perm.action).toLowerCase()
            )
          );
        });
        if (hasStrayPermission) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      return isEqual;
    });

    return _.isEqual(type.sort(), selectedSchemas.sort());
  };



  const handlePermissionChange = (checked, role, type) => {
    const targetPermissions = allPermissions.filter((perm) => {
      return (
        role.actions.includes(String(perm.action).toLowerCase()) &&
        type.includes(perm.type)
      );
    });

    /* Let's reset list and remove all included from the type */
    let newPermisssions = [
      ...selectedPermissions.filter((perm) => {
        return !type.includes(perm.type);
      }),
    ];

    if (checked) {
      setSelectedPermissions([...newPermisssions, ...targetPermissions]);
    } else {
      setSelectedPermissions(newPermisssions);
    }
  };



    {STUDENT_ROLES_PERMISSIONS.map((role, index) => {
      return (
        <td key={index}>
          <Checkbox
            disabled={action === 'view' ? true : !allPermissions.length}
            checked={isCheked(role, type)}
            indeterminate={handleIndeterminate(role, type)}
            onChange={(event) =>
              handlePermissionChange(event.target.checked, role, type)
            }
          />
        </td>
      );
    })}
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the `isCheked` function too?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I just posted it, please see

Comment: @evolutionxbox what are you passing in `type` argument for STUDENT_ROLES_PERMISSIONS? looks like the problem in logic inside `isChecked` function it always returns true for STUDENT_ROLES_PERMISSIONS checkboxes

Comment: @Oro sorry I'm not the asker.

Comment: @Oro, none. is there a way to the function is still the same eventhough the `Student` dont have `type`?

Comment: and that `isChecked` code is sucks, need to improvised.

Comment: is there any work around on that?